# How to specify the url for specific app?

Tags: salesforce

Say I have a couple of app( App A, App B, App C ) and my domain name is mycompany.salesforce.com
where can I specify so that my app url is appa.mycompanrey.salesforce.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Salesforce doesnt assign subdomains for applications/packages. Instead, it provides [subdomains for managed packages](https://na7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/register_namespace_prefix.htm), like `https://namespace.na1.visual.force.com/00A987654321`.

If you were using Salesforce Sites then you would be able to [register a domain](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/cookbook/Content/sites_using_custom_domain.htm) instead of using `www.salesforce.com`.